# how to resolve unable to start embedded tomcat server in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, tomcat

I have a given springboot application, i would like to launch it but i get this error :
*Unable to start embedded Tomcat*
I manipulated both tomcat and glassfish external servers that is why i shut them down.
I tried to change the port in my application with `server.port` property but it does not work. i also make sure external tomcat server is not running.
My embedded tomcat version is 9.0.22
[image]

Comment: Earlier log output should show why the embedded Tomcat server couldn't be started. Please add that output (as text rather than a screenshot) to your question.

Comment: Show us all of the log output. We're not even seeing an error message that could be interpreted as requiring a s port number change.